# Most memorable programming videos/podcasts

Tags: video, podcast

Which videos, podcasts, presentatations do you think are a must watch for a programmer? I was watching [Doug Crockford's lectures](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/) on JavaScript and wanted to know what else have I missed.

I'm looking for content from which I can learn from so launches of products, such as Windows or Macs, just don't cut it.

Comment: mark this as community-wiki if you want it to survive closing, and also include the link to the videos you mention to make it more usable to others..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sketchpad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=495nCzxM9PI)

[The Mother of all Demos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfIgzSoTMOs)

Answer (score 2):

Linus Torvalds on git (at Google): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8

Comment: It's actually good, eventhough he spends most of the talk bashing every other VCS he can think of. :)

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Python or Understanding Python

On Google Video: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=7760178035196894549

Answer (score 1):

RailsCasts are a quite awesome series of learning Ruby on Rails: http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 1):

I liked [The Mighty Dictionary (#55)](http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/12/) presentation from PyCon 2010 because it has a lot of details about what's going on under the hood along with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Zed Shaw on [ACLs](http://vimeo.com/2723800).

Answer (score 1):

Binky on pointers:

> **[Pointer fun with Binky](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/)**